# Can I override a string return type functions in c++

Tags: c++, string, stl, overriding

I cannot understand why this does not compile:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


class Product {

public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
  virtual void slog() = 0;
  virtual void loft() = 0;
};

class Bike: public Product {

private:
  string s;

public:

  Bike(string x){ 
    s = x;
  }

  void print() { 
    std::cout << "Bike"; 
  }

  int slog() {
    return 4;
  }

  string loft() {
    return s;
  }
};

int main() {   
  string s("Hello");
  Product *p = new Bike(s);   
  p->print(); //works fine
  cout << p->slog();//works fine    
  cout << p->loft(); //error
  return 0; 
}
```

1. The above code results in error. Why can't I override string class.
2. I want to call `loft()` using the pointer `p`.
3. Is there any way to achieve this using pointer object to abstract class `Product`

Comment: You don't _override_ `std::string`. Please fix your terminolgy. Show the verbatim errors you get with your code please.

Comment: Please next time, make you code more readable. It will go much smoother for you in the long run too :)

Comment: I would start to look at `line 30:7: error: virtual function 'slog' has a different return type ('int') than the function it overrides (which has return type 'void')
  int slog() { ... ` and work myself through the errors from top (often more meaningful, to repair first error, then rerun, as the optical noise of "follow-up errors" from an initial one, are unproductive. if there is something not repairable just copy the remaining error in above question and look if people can help further. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to include string `#include <string>`.

Comment: Thanks for replying @izzak_pyzaak
. But s is  instantiated in Bike constructor. I tried even what you said.The problem is not with s. Compiler is saying expected int return type in place of string.

Comment: Have you added `#include <string>`

Comment: yes I added string header. Compiler is saying you can not return any return type except int or void in function overriding.

Comment: he initialized `s`.

Comment: Yes didn't see, let me remove.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with `loft` method, you have a problem with `print` method. Child class has a return type of `string` and base class has a return type of `void`, thus you're not really overriding the function. Compiler sees the declaration of `void print()` in base class and you can't do a `cout` on that.
Here's your code with few fixes and comments on them, it should work fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Product {
public:        
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual int slog() = 0;
    virtual string loft() = 0;
    //added virtual destructor so you can use pointer to base class for child classes correctly
    virtual ~Product() {};
};

class Bike: public Product {
    string s;
public:
    Bike(string x) {
        s = x;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "Bike";
    }
    int slog() {
        return 4;
    }
    string loft() {
        return s;
    }
};

int main() {
    string s("Hello");
    Product *p = new Bike(s);
    p->print(); 
    cout << p->slog(); 
    cout << p->loft(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Also, please try to format your code better next time, it makes it easier to read

Comment: Thanks for replying @buld0zzr
print function return type is void only see I had updated the previous code.Actually we can't return any return type in function overriding except void and int

Comment: @HrudwikChowdary now your code compiles and runs just fine for me, just add virtual destructor to parent class

Comment: @HrudwikChowdary you might have marked wrong answer as accepted, including string header doesn't really do anything useful